# Dowloaded Wubi.exe but it doesn't run on my asus 1005p ee pc running windows 7

Tags: wubi

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS along side windows 7 on my Asus 1005P Eee PC. I tried to install it with the Live USB created with the "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.0.2.exe" but failed. Alternatively, I downloaded the "wubi.exe" installer from www.ubuntu.com, but it does not run on my pc.   Is this version of ubuntu incompatible for the given hardware for side by side installation with windows 7?

Comment: what is the error? where it is failed.. some message.. logs!! Need more data

Comment: 1) The Live USB actually runs, but when I follow the standard installation wizard it does not continue the installation. Instead it reboots.

Comment: 2.) On clicking the wubi installer I get the standard Windows warning (which displays information about the publisher) and beyond that the installer does not run.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation problem on my ASUS 1005P Eee PC Netbook.

Turns out when I purchased the Netbook it came with 4 partitions (C: D: and 2 Hidden partions) all of them were set as primary drives. Therefore, while attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 from the Live USB I would get the option to "install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" instead of "install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" and on continuing with the wizard the system will just reboot.

Then I shrunk the C drive using Windows disk management utility and tried installing Ubuntu onto the un-allocated space from the Live USB, but the installation wizard indicated that the unallocated space was not usable.

So I installed EASEUS Partition Master and used it to convert D drive to 'logical' as the C drive contained the Windows boot loader.

Thereafter, when I ran the Live USB it showed the "install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" option and I was able to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 without any problems.